# Iterate python lists inside other lists

Tags: python

Im having a problem to iterate between 2 lists to see if one of them has the elements of the other. Inside of one of those lists, I have another list. Sometimes this list have only strings, sometimes strings and.. another list.

So here is the problem. If It has strings only, I would like to know if `ALL` of those strings are inside the `Mainlist`.

But, If I have srtings `AND` another list.. I would like to know if `ALL` of the strings outside the list are in the `Mainlist` and if `AT LEAST ONE` string inside the list are in the `Mainlist`.

---

So, lets say I have a Mainlist:
`Mainlist = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']`

Now, I have other list that I want to iterate over this `Mainlist`:

`list1 = [['AA', ['BB', 'YY']], ['AA', 'GG']]`

On `list1` I have two lists : `['AA', ['BB', 'YY']]` and `['AA', 'GG']` One has only strings and the other has strings and another list.

Now I need to know if the elements on `list1` are on `Mainlist` and get the index of the ones at `list1` that give me a `True` result.

In this case, it wolud be `True`at `index 0`. Because `Mainlist` has items `'AA'`and `'BB'` .

---

other examples:

```
list2 = [['AA', 'JJ'], ['EE', 'FF']] # False at index 0 = Mainlist does not have 'JJ' / True at index 1 = Mainlist has 'EE' and 'FF'
list3 = [['AA', 'KK', ['BB', 'CC']], ['JJ', 'GG']] # False at index 0 item 'KK' is not in Mainlist / False at index 1 = Mainlist does not have 'JJ' and 'GG'
list4 = [['EE', 'FF', "OO"], ['AA', 'BB', 'CC',['DD', 'MM']], ['GG', ['BB', 'CC', 'DD']]] #False at index 0 = Mainlist does not have 'OO' / True at index 1  = Even if 'MM' is not in Mainlist, 'DD' is. / False  at index 2 = 'GG' is not in Mainlist
```

I am having a headache trying to achive that.. Does anyone has a hint that could help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You mentioned:  1. What is expected when the list_n has only strings    2. What is expected when the list_n has strings AND other lists.  What is expected when it has only other lists?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, returning a dictionary that has each index and its respective boolean:

```
list2 = [['AA', 'JJ'], ['EE', 'FF']] # False at index 0 = Mainlist does not have 'JJ' / True at index 1 = Mainlist has 'EE' and 'FF'
list3 = [['AA', 'KK', ['BB', 'CC']], ['JJ', 'GG']] # False at index 0 item 'KK' is not in Mainlist / False at index 1 = Mainlist does not have 'JJ' and 'GG'
list4 = [['EE', 'FF', "OO"], ['AA', 'BB', 'CC',['DD', 'MM']], ['GG', ['BB', 'CC', 'DD']]] #False at index 0 = Mainlist 
Mainlist = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']


def func(ls):
    dct={}
    for idx,l in enumerate(ls):
        if all(isinstance(elem, str) for elem in l):
            dct.update({idx:all(elem in Mainlist for elem in l)})
        else:
            cond=all(el in Mainlist for el in [i for i in l if isinstance(i, str)]) and any(ele in Mainlist for el in [i for i in l if isinstance(i, list)] for ele in el)
            dct.update({idx:cond})
    return dct

print(func(list2))
print(func(list3))
print(func(list4))
```

Ouput:

```
{0: False, 1: True}
{0: False, 1: False}
{0: False, 1: True, 2: False}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. You can find the explanations as comments:

```
list1 = [['AA', ['BB', 'YY']], ['AA', 'GG']]  # True, False
list2 = [['AA', 'JJ'], ['EE', 'FF']]  # False at index 0 = Mainlist does not have 'JJ' / True at index 1 = Mainlist has 'EE' and 'FF'
list3 = [['AA', 'KK', ['BB', 'CC']], ['JJ', 'GG']]  # False at index 0 item 'KK' is not in Mainlist / False at index 1 = Mainlist does not have 'JJ' and 'GG'
list4 = [['EE', 'FF', "OO"], ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', ['DD', 'MM']], ['GG', ['BB', 'CC', 'DD']]]  # False at index 0 = Mainlist does not have 'OO' / True at index 1  = Even if 'MM' is not in Mainlist, 'DD' is. / False  at index 2 = 'GG' is not in Mainlist

Mainlist = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', 'FF']


def eval_list(lst):
    r = []
    for sublist in lst:
        if all(isinstance(i, str) for i in sublist):       # if everything is str
            r.append(all(i in Mainlist for i in sublist))  # check if all of them in Mainlist
        else:                                              # else
            r.append(
                all(isinstance(item, str) and item in Mainlist # check if item is in Mainlist if it is str
                    or                                         # or 
                    any(i in Mainlist for i in item)           # check any i in item is in Mainlist
                        for item in sublist)                   # for every item in sublist
                )

    return r

for lst in [list1, list2, list3, list4]:
    print(eval_list(lst))
```

```
[True, False]
[False, True]
[False, False]
[False, True, False]
```